# What is a pass-through request?

Tags: express

This is spoken in the context of a guide on express.js.  Here is the quote:

> Static middleware enables pass-through requests for static assets.

Googling doesn't yield a definition like I thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "pass-through" in this context means that static files on disk "pass through" express without any processing or modification and are sent directly to the browser, in contrast to dynamic requests which involve generating new and dynamic HTML in response to a browser request (using templates and databases, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

For example, we have this code at `http://example.org`

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('*',function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello');
});
```

For example, we open by browser the url `http://example.org/somefile.txt`

if there is file of `somefile.txt` in folder of `public/` , it is returned, but if the file doesn't exists, the request is passed to other controllers, in this case to `app.get('*',...)`

So, the client recieves the response with `Hello`